# Compiler Error Message: CS0433 The type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

i'm using MVC5 in visual studio 2013, when i'm running my project that time i'm getting error as while project build successfully:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_5.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.MVC.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ac088797\ac28303c\assembly\dl3\af0a60ce\a6fbe2c8_3cb3d001\System.Web.Mvc.DLL'
```

Comment: I hope you have already tried `the ultimate fixes for MS issues` like cleaning solution, restarting VS, clearing temp files etc.?

Comment: yes, i have also replaced .dll files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error occurs when a view is compiled, which unless you've changed the project settings, doesn't occur at build time.

As the file `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ac088797\ac28303c\assembly\dl3\af0a60ce\a6fbe2c8_3cb3d001\System.Web.Mvc.DLL` is in a temporary folder, can you delete it and try again?

Do you get the same result?

Comment: not able to delete this .dll file due to permission issues

Answer (score 0):

i did it after adding new updated System.Web.MVC.dll file for MVC5